# External progam not returning correct value - assembly

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, dosbox

I have made 2 programs - 1 is a main function, the other is an external function. Both codes seem to be written correctly, but I am not being given a correct value from the external program.

here is the main program:

```
EXTRN SWAPPROC:FAR
INCLUDE io.h

Cr        EQU  0DH       ; carriage return
Lf        EQU  0AH       ; line feed

TheStack  SEGMENT STACK
          DW   100H DUP (?)
TheStack  ENDS

Data      SEGMENT
Num       Dw   ?
Num2      Dw   ?
Prompt1   DB   'Please enter the positive integer of your choice:  ', 0
Prompt2   DB   'Please enter another positive integer of your choice:  ', 0
String    DB   40 DUP (?)
New   DB   6 DUP (?), 0
New2      DB   6 DUP (?), 0
Data      ENDS

Code      SEGMENT
          ASSUME Cs:Code, Ds:Data

Start:    Mov Ax, SEG Data    ; Load Data Segment Number.
          Mov Ds, Ax

Prompt:   Output Prompt1      ; Prompt for first number.
          Inputs String, 40   ; Read the ASCII characters.    
      AToI String      
          Mov Num, Ax 
      Output Prompt2      ; Prompt for first number.
          Inputs String, 40   ; Read the ASCII characters.    
      AToI String      
      Mov Num2, Ax
          mov Ax, num 
      mov bx, num2
      Itoa new, ax
      Itoa new2, bx
      Output new
      Output new2
      Lea ax, num
      push ax
      Lea bx, num2
      push bx
      call swapproc
      Itoa new, ax
      Itoa new2, bx
      output new
      Output new2



Quit:     Mov Al, 0           ; Put return code of zero in Al.
          Mov Ah, 4CH         ; Put DOS function call in Ah.
          int 21H             ; Call DOS

Code      ENDS
          END  Start
```

and this is the external program:

```
public swapproc

code     segment
     assume cs:code

SWAPPROC  PROC  FAR

     push ax
     push bx    

main:    

         mov dx, 0
     div bx
     Mov AX, [bx]
     mov [bx], Dx
     cmp dx, 0
     jne main
     POP BX 
     POP AX
     ret

swapproc endp
code     ends
     end
```

for example, when I enter the values of 12 and 4 into the first program, they are returned correctly, but when the other program is called, none of the values are returned correctly, or at least aren't in the right registers. so since the GCD of 12 and 4 is 4, I should be returned the values of 0 - the final remainder - and 4 - the GCF - from the other program. instead, no matter what values are put in, I am always returned 0 and 2. Combining the programs into 1 showed that the math coding was correct. I have linked the programs using tlink by using the command tlink mainprog+swapproc+io. both during the assembly of the programs with TASM and linking with tlink, no errors or warnings were present. I seem to be stuck going around in a circle on a wild goose chase by making minor edits to the external program and the main program only to be stuck with the same issue. It's causing headaches, frustration, and confusion for me since I have made sure that all the programs were correctly written and had no typos or missing commands - to my knowledge at least. What would cause 2 perfectly written programs to end up with 1 of them returning incorrect values? What do I need to do in order to make the second program return the correct values? Is this an issue with the DOS emulator I'm using (dos box)? Or is this issue too complex to understand and fix?

Comment: Have you tried without [] around bx in swapproc?

Comment: @TerjeD. I did, still no luck. I've evensubtracted 2 from the stack pointer before calling and even tried to do this:          Mov bx, [bp+8]
  mov ax, bx
  mov bx, [bp+6] to the swapproc program before proceeding into the arithmetic. it still doesn't seem to work. I keep getting returned the values 2 and 0.